# monkeyrunner is not in the sdk "tools" folder

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I have SDK tools and SDK Platform-Tools installed but I don't see monkeyrunner in the tools folder. What gives? is there a different way of running a monkeyrunner script?

Comment: Check inside tools/bin

Comment: I see it now. It's there